# Move files from folder to root of doc library using sharepoint 2010 workflow template in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, sharepoint-library

i am using a sp2010 wf template on my sp2013 onprem library. I need to move a file inside a folder, back to the root of the library using this workflow. I am trying to set the path and name to relative path or just currentitem:name but nothing works. it works when moving the files within the folders but not back to the root path.
i tried
`"http://testsite/testlibrary/[Current Item:Name]"'
"/testlibrary/[Current Item:Name]"
"testlibrary/[Current Item:Name]"
"/[Current Item:Name]"
"[Current Item:Name]"`

Answer (score 0):

We are not able to use workflow to move file from folder to root document library in SharePoint.

As workarounds, we can use Content and structure in site settings to move documents, or use code to move, or use "Copy list item" and "delete item" action in workflow.

Reference: [How to move documents from sub folders to the root folder](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135137/how-to-move-documents-from-sub-folders-to-the-root-folder)